# How would I update phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I want to update my current version of phpMyAdmin. I have deleted everything in the xampp phpMyAdmin folder apart from the config.php and added the new files from the new phpMyAdmin zip as advised. But the new version still won't appear in localhost. Is it a possibilty I will have to wait overnight until the changes are made?

Comment: Do you get an error message when visiting the phpMyAdmin http location?

Comment: No, it just hadn't updated. But the old version still was running and working.

Comment: If you delete the phpMyAdmin folder, is the old version still working? If so, you did not pick the correct folder.

Comment: Yeah, I deleted the phpMyAdmin folder and the old version still worked. God knows whats happened. Oh, I discovered Apache, MySql and PHP is running ALONG with Xampp. I wonder if that has something to do with it?

Comment: Yes He knows but now you'll have to find out. Have a look at XAMPP's http configuration to find an alias pointing to another directory for phpMyAdmin. About your last comment, XAMPP is not running anything, it installs the other components.

Comment: (Well, XAMPP is running a control panel on its own, to drive the other components).

Comment: If you have both XAMPP along side your own MySQL, Apache, and PHP you could be getting all kinds of conflicts. I suggest selecting one or the other to use and removing the other (being careful to backup any website or database you wish to preserve). Once you've isolated that part of the problem, you can look in to what works and what the access/error logs have to say.

Comment: Yeah, it works now after deleting Xampp and using just MySQL, Apache and php. I put the new phpMyAdmin download in the Apache folder and that's done it.